# CPU slower than GPU

Tags: cycles-render-engine

[image][image]

I have an AMD 2700X and an RTX 2800, for some reason my CPU will stay on a rendered tile for 54 seconds every single time and wont move on. But you can see the one tile that my GPU is just speeding through. Does anyone know what's happening and how to fix it? It is a simple little animation with only a cube that I used bezel on and the quick smoke effect. I'm brand new and was just playing around with the setting. I looked up plenty of "Make render times faster." Videos and none of them helped. Your help is greatly needed and very appreciated!

Comment: Correction, my CPU DOES move on, but takes around 50 second to a minute every tile

Comment: Please see https://www.take-a-screenshot.org/

Answer (score 5):

This is normal. The GPU you have is apparently faster at rendering than the CPU you have. It is not surprising and there is nothing to do about this, nothing to fix, this is just how it is.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a hardware issue. When you are processing with a CPU, what is being rendered is based on the number of cores that you have and what programs are also using the processing power. That's what's being used in the Blender Internal Render Engine. When it comes to the Cycles engine, that's based on how powerful the graphic card is. There is a video from Blender Guru that gives you a couple of tips needed to speed up the process, but that's only if you haven't finalized yet. The only way a CPU based render for an animation will ever rival a graphics card is by using a renderfarm as a collective.

Other than that, you may have to get rid of some background programs that are running and it might give it a boost.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gJf46RPyejg